# Why does this code work apart from the 1st 11th 13th 14th?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-search

```
print('This is a binary search!')
list1 = [1,3,6,9,12,23,67,68,69,71,74,86,95,100]

find = int(input('Which item would you like to find?'))

found = 0

def half(value):
    if value % 2 == 1:
        value = (float(value) / 2) + 0.5
        return int(value)
    else:
        return int(value / 2)

length = len(list1)
cal = half(length)
pal = 0
while found == 0:
    fund = int(list1[int(cal)])
    if int(fund) == find:
        print(str(cal + 1) + ' is the reference!')
        found = 1
    if fund > find:
        cal = half(cal)
    if fund < find:
        cal = half(cal) + cal
```

Why does this not work for only certain values in the list, I am trying to create a binary search program.

Comment: What does not work mean? Show an example.

Comment: there is the error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Downloads\Binary Search.py", line 20, in <module>
    fund = int(list1[int(cal)])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I can't read your mind. Please edit your question with *all* relevant information

Comment: sorry edited it

Comment: and if you search for the first element in the list it doesnt do anything!

Comment: `half(length)` isn’t right for that implementation of `half`, which will round 0.5 upwards. Just implement `half` as `return value // 2`. You also need to halve the size of the range you’re searching, not the index, so do something with `pal`. It’s probably a good idea to use more descriptive names, too.

Comment: Adding a comment is not editing the question. Please click on the "edit" button below the tags to edit the question itself.

Comment: So, try again, like so: keep track of the lowest and highest index you’re searching, write a function to get the middle of those indexes, and while the middle index doesn’t contain the value you’re looking for, set the lowest index to the index after the middle if the value is higher and the highest index to the index before the middle if the value is lower.

Comment: Okay I will try that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print('This is a binary search!')
list1 = [1,3,6,9,12,23,67,68,69,71,74,86,95,100]

find = int(input('Which item would you like to find?'))
#This shows that the program has not found the number.
found = 0
#This function finds half of the value.
def half(value):
    return value // 2
#This fidns the length of the list. 
length = len(list1)
#This is the starting middle value.
cal = half(length)
#This is the lower bound.
pal = 0
#This is the upper bound.
sal = len(list1)
#This makes a limit for if the item is not in the list.
gal = 2*(len(list1))
#This keeps track of how many times the while loop is triggered.
mal = 0
#This makes it keep trying.
while found == 0:
    #This clocks the amount of times the while loop is triggered.
    mal = mal  + 1
    #This retrieves the value from the list.
    fund = int(list1[int(cal)])
    #If fund is find then it has found the element.
    if int(fund) == find:
        #This print the place in the list.clear
        print(str(cal + 1) + ' is the reference!')
        #This ends the while loop.
        found = 1
    #This checks if it is lower than the guess.
    if fund > find:
        #It brings down the upper bound.
        sal = cal
    #This checks if it is higher than the guess.
    if fund < find:
        #This brings up the lower bound.
        pal = cal
    #This adjusts cal.
    cal = half(sal + pal)
    #This stops the program after a number of attempts.
    if mal > gal:
        #This tells the user that it is not in the list.
        print('Your number is not in the list!')
        #This ends the while loop.
        found = 1
```

WOO